# Why is Form.CanFocus false in an unit test only when debugging the test?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, mstest

In an unit test, a `Form`'s property `CanFocus` has the value `false` when debugging the test, and `true` when running the test.

The code of the test simplified is below:

```
// Arrange
Form f = new Form();

// Act
f.Show();
Application.DoEvents();

// Assert
// The following LOC:
// Debugging the test? Fails. Running the test? Passes.
Assert.IsTrue(f.CanFocus);
```

I also tried putting these lines directly above `f.Show()`:

```
f.Shown += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    f.Activate();
};
```

From what I've heard, direct UI methods should not be checked, but I am still curious about the situation above.

**Update:** I checked and at the moment of the assertion in debug mode, `f` has the properties `IsHandleCreated`, `Visible` and `Enabled` set to `true`. I also see that when debugging the test, the window is not actually visible.

The situation is that I am doing an unit test for a method that should focus a control. The method uses the control's own property `HasFocus` (sets it to `true`) only when the control is created (`!= null`) and its property `IsDisposed` is set to `false`. I wish to know, in the best case, in what should the unit test for this method consist of.

Comment: There is no UI when unit testing. That is why.

Comment: It helps to look into [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,1378). This property returns `false` if window handle is not created or not visible/enabled.

Comment: @Sinatr I updated the question with more details. Thank you.

Comment: Nobody ever understands what DoEvents() does, largely because it is unknowable.  Makes it a very dangerous method.  You could only make this test succeed by repeatedly calling it, until CanFocus becomes true.  Necessary because the Show() method causes many messages to be dispatched.  Something you can see by overriding WndProc() and using Debug.WriteLine(m);  Do not assume that what you now see is predictable and repeatable.